# Flask-Dance Error: Scope has changed

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-oauthlib

I am using [flask-dance](http://flask-dance.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to authenticate to Google's servers.

Config for flask-dance:

```
from flask.ext.dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint
google_blueprint = make_google_blueprint (
    client_id=app.config['GOOGLE']['client_id'],
    client_secret=app.config['GOOGLE']['client_secret'],
    scope=["profile", "email"],
    redirect_to="main.index",
    login_url="/",
    authorized_url="/authorized",
)
app.register_blueprint(google_blueprint,url_prefix="/login")
```

However, I am getting `Warning: Scope has changed from "profile email" to "".` after you go through Google's credential dialog box.

Here's the full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_dance/consumer/oauth2.py", line 168, in authorized
    client_secret=self.client_secret,
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 199, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py", line 409, in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 376, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)
  File "/home/xxx/.virtualenvs/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 406, in validate_token_parameters
    raise w
Warning: Scope has changed from "profile email" to "".
```

On the Chrome Dev Console I get this (after the Account Chooser window right before the traceback):

```
GET http://localhost:5000/login/authorized?state=11rtXcAHJm0jloiDpM8IrazD9uLT3b…xnXM0ZB1DumOPqFOgu-x19CDSbDfQoKLWVEfBRTQIg.gvDk1rm330AV3oEBd8DOtNAR0Vr7lQI 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
Navigated to http://localhost:5000/login/authorized?state=11rtXcAHJm0jloiDpM8IrazD9uLT3b…xnXM0ZB1DumOPqFOgu-x19CDSbDfQoKLWVEfBRTQIg.gvDk1rm330AV3oEBd8DOtNAR0Vr7lQI
```

If I do `os.environ['OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE'] = '1'` it works, but I don't think this is a solution but more of a workaround for now. :(

I opened a ticket on the issue [Google OAuth2 returns no scope on authentication breaks scope test #306](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib/issues/306) on the issue.

From what I can tell from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3, Google isn't required to return the scope (unless the scope was changed), am I reading this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearest thing I can figure is there is a bug in the [oauthlib](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib) plugin which I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib/issues/306) with already.

From the bug report, you can fix the issue by changing the file `/oauth2/rfc6749/tokens.py` in the plugin on Line 30 from `self._new_scope = set(utils.scope_to_list(params.get('scope', '')))` to `self._new_scope = set(utils.scope_to_list(params.get('scope', old_scope)))`

Fix was merged: https://github.com/idan/oauthlib/pull/323