# Is it a requirement of RFC-6749 to return scope params when the scope doesn't change?

Tags: oauth-2.0

From what I can tell from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3, Isn't required to return the scope (unless the scope was changed), am I reading this correctly?

I noticed that Google wasn't sending while I was troubleshooting [#28011269](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011269/flask-dance-error-scope-has-changed), is this normal, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Authorization Server may choose **not** to send a `scope` value in the response if **all** of the requested scopes in the client's request were granted. If any of the requested scopes were not granted, it **must** return the actual granted scopes.

Also, if the client did not request any specific scopes, it may choose not to return a `scope` value assuming that it has a documented default value and the client knows about it, or else it may fail the request indicating an invalid scope.

Comment: I am still new at Oauth authentication. I wasn't sure if I was looking correctly. Though, it does show that Plython's oauthlib application has a bug when using the Google's oauth2. Thanks for the information, Hans.